# what does Spark build mean

Tags: apache-spark, build, hive

In spark official site,i see "Hive support is enabled by adding the -Phive and -Phive-thriftserver flags to Spark’s build." .I am confused,what does "Spark build" mean,and how "-Phive "and "-Phive-thriftserver" works?

Comment: "Building" a program generally means recompiling it. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html

Comment: thanks,very appreciate